# WinUI 3 and Windows Community Toolkit - InitializeComponent error

Tags: windows-community-toolkit, winui-3

Attempting to use Windows Controls Toolkit with WinUI 3 using Windows App SDK 1.0.0 experimental1.

Im getting these two errors:

```
Error   CS1061  'App' does not contain a definition for 'InitializeComponent'
```

```
Error   NETSDK1022  Duplicate 'Page' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Page' items from your project directory by default.
```

Im using the WinUI in Desktop experimental project type, ie:
[image]

Looks like there is some crossover between Windows App SDK & WCT Nuget packages but what steps can I take to sort this out and use the WCT?

Answer (score 1):

Having found [this](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/4171) github issue, it seems WCT isnt compatible with WinUI 3 yet.